# Managed C++ Wrapper for C Code - Identical function names issues

Tags: c#, c++, c, .net, wrapper

I have been tasked with creating a Wrapper for a C-library to be used in C#. I have no control over the C-library's source code and I only have access to its header file and to the static library file (.lib).

I have followed several tutorials and got this working when creating an unmanaged C++ class which is wrapped using CLI/C++ and used in C#. No problem. The problem I am facing know though, is as C does not use namespaces, I have trouble figuring out how to tell the compiler when I want to call the function from the .lib file itself, rather than my identically named wrapper function. If it helps understanding, my header file only consists of function definitions, typedefs (structs, enums), but no classes (not even sure if C headers usually do?).

What I have done:

1. Created a VS C++ CLR Class Library (.NET Framework) project
2. Linked my .lib file to *all configurations* in linker->inputs as an additional dependency.
3. Created two files: *Wrapper.h* and *Wrapper.cpp*.
4. *#include*d the header file corresponding to my .lib in the *Wrapper.h* file

This is where I get a bit confused, mostly due to the tutorials all covering how to link a C++ library rather than a C library. The difference there being the lack of namespace in C, and (in my case) the lack of *class*.

Uncertainties:

1. I do not know if I need a *ref class Analytics{}* in my *Wrapper.h* or not. I assume I do if I want to use all the functions statically, but as there is no corresponding class in the C library, can I just name this whatever I want?
2. In order to properly link the C library in my header file (*Wrapper.h*), I need to use the same function definition as in the original header file. Do I repeat the use of "extern" and such keywords? Can I freely add *static* and accessibility modifiers?
3. At this point I want to "implement" the function in the *Wrapper.cpp* file. Here my problem about identical function names comes in. The function I want to implement has the same name in the original header file as it does in the Wrapper header file (obviously, as it would not work otherwise, right?). The wrapper header file contains a namespace and a class (for now class name is *Analytics*) so I can declare the function as `Analytics::void SanSetApplicationContext(){...}`, but as the original C library header file does not contain classes or namespaces, there is no way for me to call that function and distinguishing between them. The C++ compiler always prefers the local definition and I am stuck with a function calling itself for all eternity. I hope you understand my point.

I am probably doing something wrong and/or misunderstanding something, but how would you guys suggest I approach this issue? I will append my files contents below. In the files I have so far only tried implementing a single function. **Code should be fixed and hopefully working**

**Wrapper.h**

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace Wrapper {
    public ref class Analytics
    {
    public:
        static void SanSetApplicationContext(String^ ctx);
    };
}
```

**Wrapper.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Wrapper.h"
#include "../SWA_lib/Analytics.h"

namespace Wrapper {
    void Analytics::SanSetApplicationContext(String^ ctx) {
        //Convert String^ to const char*
        msclr::interop::marshal_context mCtx;
        const char* convertedStr = mCtx.marshal_as<const char*>(ctx);

        ::SanSetApplicationContext(convertedStr);
    }
}
```

**Analytics.h**

```
...
extern void SanSetApplicationContext(const char *ctx);
...
```

**Update**
Updated the code to reflect my changes made based on your comments. Thanks!

**Update 2**
@Bodo asked me to explain another issue of mine, which is how I would handle wrapping functions that return opaque handles. The example used is the following: `typedef struct SanEvent_s *SanEvent;` which is found in my C header file. So basically, this library provides an API. The API execution always starts with a call to an `Initialize();` function, and ends with a call to the `Terminate();` function. I have no previous experience of using this API, but from the documentation, I assume that all objects, references and what not are freed/destroyed when `Terminate()` is called, as none of their examples show destroying objects.
Now, creating a `SanEvent` is done like this (according to documentation):

```
SanEvent event;
event = SanNewEvent("The Main Event");
```

This opaque handle is considered protected on the C# side, so there does not seem to be a way for me of returning it all the way there. My idea is to keep the events in some kind of Collection, in the C++/CLI wrapper where the type can be used, and only return the index of the Event to C# (The index the even would have in a List or something). I am not sure this is a good idea, but this is as far as I have come with my plan. Something that represents a `SanEvent` needs to be returned to C# as I need to be able to reference the event in the future, in order to add additional information to the event via other functions. This idea would of course need tailored "helper functions" on the C++ side which mediate between C# and C. I am sorry if the information is vague, but I don't really have a lot to go on myself as of now.

Comment: Type `::SanSetApplicationContext` to ensure you call the library function.  [Explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-operator-in-c/).  And make the method friendly, its parameter needs to be `String^`.

Comment: C does not have namespaces or classes. You should not duplicate the information from the C library's header file but include it like `extern "C" {` `#include "c_library_header.h"` `}` in `Wrapper.cpp`, not in `Wrapper.h`. The interface of the wrapper code should be independent from the use of the C library in its implementation.

Comment: Prepend :: before your function name in order to access the function declared in global namespace instead of the in-class function of the same name: `::SanSetApplicationContext`

Comment: Thanks for the tip about ::. Did not know that :) @Bodo, My C-header file actually already includes "extern C" if the compiler variable __cpluplus or whatever it is called, is set. So I suppose a simple #include would be sufficient?
HansPassant Thanks for the tip about the string :)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to pass through typedefs such as structs and enums from the C-header to my Class library?

Comment: @Matheos Without seeing the actual source code (or header files) it is difficult to suggest a good solution. Depending on the types and data structures it might be better to implement your own types instead of passing the types defined for the C library. For example your C++/C# interface can use a real string type while the C interface uses a `char` pointer or array.

Comment: @Bodo Yes that is the conclusion I have come to too. Though, I am having a hard time with this one: `typedef struct SanEvent_s *SanEvent;`. This opaque pointer hides the definition of the struct in the .lib (I hope I am saying it right), but how will I emulate this in C++ and consequently in C#?

Comment: @Matheos I guess you will get the opaque pointer from some function, e.g. `openSomething`, and have to pass it to other functions, e.g. `writeSomething`. You could wrap this `openSomething` in a C++ function that creates an object which will contain the opaque pointer, and pass this object to the wrapper for `writeSomething`  etc which will extract the opaque pointer and pass it to the corresponding C function.

Comment: @Bodo Good tip. I think I kind of know where you are coming from. Though, how would I go about creating an instance of `SanEvent´ in C#? This would most definately be required. Alternatively, I would need to create C++ functions for the different events that could be needed, and simply call one of these functions from C# and have C++ handle the struct creating and further calling into C. Does my reasoning sound reasonable or am I way off?

Comment: @Matheos We are discussing possible solutions based on vague information and guessing. Please show *in your question* how you would create an instance of `struct SanEvent_s` in form of a `SanEvent` pointer in C and how you would use and free/destroy it in C. Add your additional ideas and questions to your question. Then it might be possible to write a proposal as an answer.

Comment: @Bodo I did my best to provide additional detailed info in the question

Comment: I understand `SanEvent event` as a representation of an event object, so I would create e.g. a `SanEvent` class in the `Wrapper` namespace with a protected `SanEvent event` member variable, a constructor with `string name` arg that calls `event = SanNewEvent(name.c_str());`, a destructor that calls the corresponding destroy/free function and public methods as wrappers for all C functions that use `event` as an argument. The user would create a `SanEvent` object with passing the event name to the constructor, call object methods to do something with the event and later destroy the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding "::" to the beginning of a function call tells the compiler to use the function found in global namespace rather than local namespace/class. So:

```
namespace Wrapper {
    void Analytics::SanSetApplicationContext(const char *ctx) {
        ::SanSetApplicationContext(ctx);
    }
}
```

Should call the c version correctly